# Umbraco 7.13 Azure Web Services Multiple Nodes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco, multiple-languages

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the latest version of Umbraco (7.13) running in Azure web services with multiple home nodes for various languages.

Are there any issues that I should be aware of when trying to set this up? I'm pretty new to AWS in general.

I haven't seen any walkthroughs on this procedure, so I'd appreciate any tips you all might have.

thanks!

Comment: Have you read this?https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/azure-web-apps

Comment: I had not seen that before. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could run Umbraco on Azure Web Apps, there are some configuration options and some specific Azure Web Apps environment limitations you need to be aware of.

The details you could get from this [doc](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/azure-web-apps).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: @Nick, if this answer could help you, you could mark it as the answer.Thanks!

Comment: Appologies, been away from SO for a while. Just had time to finally log back in.